# References to code sample of complex django models and views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Where can I find good code samples and best practices in building complex django model structure and (non-generic) views?

Tutorials usually comes with models and views with only one or two layers of models.  (e.g. Polls and Choices in Django tutorials)  I'm looking for code samples with hierarchy of models and best practices in building the views and controls in Django.  Any tips?  URLs?

Let say I have two parent models A and B; A has child models C, D, E; B has child models F and G; model H reference (or FK) C and D; model I is child of D and reference G?  What's the approach to build the detail display view to show all these in a single html / template?

Comment: I think django tut is fine enough. If you understand the basic, that is how models work, or what is M2M or FK etc then you will able to architect your model with ease. Best of luck

Comment: Here is a more advanced article on inheritance you will find useful, http://charlesleifer.com/blog/django-patterns-model-inheritance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking through and learning from some well written django projects on github or bitbucket. Django-cms has quite a few models and might be an example of what you're looking for:

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/tree/develop/cms/models